# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazon/android/Kiwi;

Tags: amazon-fire-tv, amazon-appstore

I have uploaded a FireTV build on amazon app store but Amazon rejected the build . I am not using any amazon library . The logs which i got from Amazon

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazon/android/Kiwi;
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at com.tv.LeanbackActivity.onCreate(LeanbackActivity.java)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1122)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2435)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:160)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5483)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:984)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.amazon.android.Kiwi" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/air.com.snagfilms-1/base.apk", zip file "/system/priv-app/DeviceMessagingAndroidSDK/DeviceMessagingAndroidSDK.apk", zip file "/system/priv-app/MetricsApi/MetricsApi.apk", zip file "/system/priv-app/com.amazon.dp.logger/com.amazon.dp.logger.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/air.com.snagfilms-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    ... 14 more
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazon.android.Kiwi
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):        ... 15 more
10-05 02:28:09.323: E/AndroidRuntime(29717):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Amazon rep says that I am using ADM (Amazon Device Messaging) in my app but I don't and my manifest has no permissions for ADM (or even GCM for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is happening if you have multidex enabled. For resolving this error you will have to do some changes.

1) Create a file name `multidex.keep` in App root folder.

2) Write `com/amazon/android/Kiwi.class` in that file.

3) Open app's `build.gradle` file and write below code in `android` tag.

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
    additionalParameters = ["--set-max-idx-number=55000"] // default 60000
}
```

4) Open app build.gradle file and inside android tag write

```
afterEvaluate {
if (!android.applicationVariants.matching { it.flavorName == 'mobile' }.isEmpty()) {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex' // enable multidex
        dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for ur input . I will check it and let u know about my observation on it.